# How do I stop constantly losing remote logon rights in Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, permissions, terminal-services

I've got a puzzling situation with my company's W2K3 server. I've discovered that the Administrator user apparently doesn't have remote logon rights, even though it is part of the Remote Desktop Users. After some searching around, I found the Terminal Services Configuration Control and directly added Administrator in with full rights. This seemed to solve the problem, allowing me to connect to the Remote Desktop on the server. But, after 2 or 3 logons, the Administrator user has lost remote logon rights *again*. I have to remove and add Administrator to the Terminal Services Configuration *again* and it's still only good for 2 or 3 logons! This is the same for any user I want to allow remote logon for. 
The maddening thing is, there were two users added by the system integrator before I came to this company, those two accounts have no problems with remote access. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, please help me!

Comment: This should be posted/moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Check out your procedure against this article:

[Enabling users to connect remotely to the server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781509%28WS.10%29.aspx)